# Write output file, collating groups of up to 7 input lines

Tags: python, file

I have this code that reads a file and after processing a few lines writes the output to a second file:

```
num_reads = 7
with open('data.txt') as read_file:
    with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as write_file:

        while (True):
            lines = []
            try:       # expect errors if the number of lines in the file are not a multiplication of num_reads
                for i in range(num_reads):     
                    lines.append(next(read_file))  # when the file finishes an exception occurs here

                #do sutff with the lines (exactly num_reads number of lines)
                processed = " ".join(list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", ''), lines)))
                write_file.write(processed + '\n')

            except StopIteration:     # here we process the (possibly) insufficent last lines
                #do stuff with the lines (less that  num_reads)
                processed = " ".join(list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", ''), lines)))
                write_file.write(processed + '\n')
                break
```

Here is the input file (`data.txt`):

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line7
line8
line9
```

And this is the output file that has the desired state:

```
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line7
line8 line9
```

This works correctly but as I wish to do the same processing and writing procedure in both cases (when the number of elements is 7 and when the file finishes and the exception is raised) I think the above code violates DRY principle even if I define a new function and call it once in `try` block and once in `except` before `break`. Any other ordering that I could come up with was either causing an infinite loop or losing the final lines. 
I appreciate any comments on handling this issue, as it is not limited to this case and I had faced it in other cases as well.

Comment: @200_success done! :)

Comment: (Welcom to Code Review!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: This question belongs to Stack Overflow, and I voted to migrate it. Therefore, the answer is not a review.

Keep in mind that principles are there to guide you. They should be treated like guard rails, rather than roadblocks.

I would argue that

```
    while (....) {
        foo(7);
    }
    foo(3);
```

does *not* violate DRY. Your situation is pretty much the same.

That said, your idea of defining function is valid. You just factoring out the wrong code. Factor out reading. Consider

```
    def read_n_lines(infile, n):
        lines = []
        try:
            for _ in range(n):
                lines.append(next(infile))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        return lines
```

and use it as

```
    while True:
        lines = read_n_lines(infile, 7)
        if len(lines) == 0:
            break
        process_lines(lines)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Beautiful idea. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid writing code with exception-handling altogether.  Usually, when you want to write a fancy loop in Python, the `itertools` module is your friend.  In this case, I would take advantage of [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to form groups of lines, assisted by [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to provide the line numbers.

```
import itertools

def chunks(iterable, n):
    i = itertools.count()
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(iterable, lambda _: next(i) // n):
        yield group

with open('data.txt') as read_f, open('new_data.txt', 'w') as write_f:
    for group in chunks(read_f, 7):
        print(' '.join(line.rstrip() for line in group), file=write_f)
```

A few other minor changes:

- You only need one `with` block to open both files.
- `line.rstrip()` is more convenient than `lambda x: x.replace("\n", '')`
- `print(…, file=write_file)` is slightly more elegant than `write_file.write(… + '\n')`.

Comment: Isn't the `grouper` recipe more appropriate to make fixed-length chunks? Or did you purposefully avoid it to avoid dealing with the fill values at the end of the iteration?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger The `grouper()` recipe works best for complete groups; you would have to specify a `fillvalue`, then strip out that padding.

Comment: @Graipher I don't see any reason to copy a recipe that doesn't do what we want, then work around the unwanted behavior by stripping off junk.

Comment: @200_success: I agree now that it is too cumbersome. We should probably clean up the comments.